# Best architecture for many asynchronous Realm writes

Tags: asynchronous, realm

I'm getting crashes from Realm writes already being in a transaction, due to Realm data being updated from several asynchronous network callbacks. I understand *why* Realm is crashing, but I'm wondering what the right architecture is here.

So far, I can minimize the crashes by moving the individual write transactions to background threads, but is this the recommended best practice? It relies on me remembering to do this every time. Or should the network requests all be run through some central clearing house, which then moves callbacks (and therefore writes) onto background threads? Or are background threads not even the right way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

background writes are fine with Realm (encouraged even!) but one thing you should watch out for is that if the background queue is marked as [concurrent](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Conceptual/ConcurrencyProgrammingGuide/OperationQueues/OperationQueues.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008091-CH102-SW2), then the same thread might be reused for the same queue, meaning that GCD might schedule one of your blocks to run while another is in the middle of a write transaction.

The best way to resolve this is to ensure that your GCD queue doing the writing is marked as serial, not concurrent.

Comment: Even with serial GCD queues, the only guarantee is that blocks submitted to that queue will not run concurrently. It does not guarantee that blocks submitted to that queue will always be on the same thread.